# Why isnt my pictures whole when I use background image using style property

Tags: html, css

Why are the pictures not filling, when I use style property for background-image url.
What is shown on the page :  [image]

```css
  body {
    background-image: url("../Bilder/ikkephotoshopped.jpg"), 
                    url("../Bilder/photoshopped.jpg" );
    }
```

the pictures suppose to go into the page
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post some HTML. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i solved this problem

Comment: yes this do be answering my question, and my prayers, god bless

Answer (score 0):

```
  body {
    background-image: url("../Bilder/ikkephotoshopped.jpg");
    background-image:  url("../Bilder/photoshopped.jpg" );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

i had to use the background-image property twice, that was the solution